# C++14 Smart Pointers: Why this output?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived::ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived::dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
```

The correct output is:

```
Base::ctor
Derived::ctor
Base::dtor
```

But according to me, it should be:

```
Base::ctor
Derived::ctor
Derived::dtor
Base::dtor
```

Can someone explain why this order of output ??
Why does it not follow the intended order ?

Comment: Make `~Base()` virtual

Comment: You have UB in your code, make destructor virtual

Comment: I know that Boost's `shared_pointer` did that, at the cost of an additional allocation for the pointer management structure. I think that this feature was carried over into the C++ 11 standard.

Comment: You need to declare the base class destructor as virtual to let the compiler know it should look up the destructor in the vtable of the derived class.

Comment: This code would have produced the same output if using raw pointers with `new` and `delete`, fyi. [Here is what your code should look like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S41B8EncTR3BSojH)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that's correct. A crucial part of what makes that easy to adopt is that the Deleter isn't part of the `shared_ptr`'s type, whereas it is a template argument to the `unique_ptr`

Comment: I guess what confuses me are the unique_ptr and make_unique constructs. Any source to understand these better?